How do you manage register usage with cufft LTO callbacks?
When swapping cuFFT callbacks from the legacy callbacks to the new LTO callbacks, I encountered errors with certain FFT sizes combined with certain FFT callbacks. The error would occur when calling cufftXtMakePlanMany after setting a JIT store callback.
Example error:
error   : entry function '_Z12body_lto_fftILj32E3EPTIJLj8EEELj32ELj10EL9padding_t6EL8layout_t0EjfEv18kernel_arguments_tIT5_E' with max regcount of 48 calls function '_Z28cufftJITCallbackStoreComplexPvy6float2S_S_' with regcount of 54
Adding --maxrregcount 30 when compiling the callback fatbin appears to help the issue, but I'm worried that isn't a permanent fix, and may have negative performance impacts.
My application derives sizes from a user-defined config file, so the callbacks will usually work, but occasionally the size will get too large and the program will fail with this error. I believe the register bounds are being imposed inside the cuFFT library, so it's difficult to tell what's going to happen without just running it and hitting the error.

Have you looked at this?

@BrendanLynn, that link makes sense, thanks! My question is really more targeted at whether there is a way to know how many registers are available for callbacks before linking/running. I've updated my question some to make that more clear.
